# Hibernate auto import false for all hibernate mappings

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

Is there any way to tell hibernate that i want all the hbm.xml files to be marked with flag auto-import=false.

Answer (score 2):

Did you mean this?

```
<hibernate-mapping package="org.huahsin" auto-import="false">
   <class ...>
      ...
      ...
   </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```